# Questions about conditional statements in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I am new to scilab and trying to grapple with how row and column matrix are handled.
if I do

```
 k=1:10;
 d=k*3
```

I get a row

```
for k=1:10
d=k*3;
disp(d)
end
```

produces a column.
I want to use wavewrite function which needs a row matrix but I want to use conditional
statements in my code and if I write

```
 k=1:10;
 if k==5
 d=7
 else
 d=k*3
```

It ignores if,else.
I've tried d=d' to transpose in the second example but it doesn't display transposed at least.

Comment: Ok I figured it out. matrix(d,1,-1) converts column array to matrix row.

Answer (score 0):

It's old but there are a lot of misunderstanding.

When you write:

```
k=1:10;
```

Your variable k is a matrix with 1 line and 10 columns. In other words a row.

if you want a column:

```
k=(1:10)';
```

The operator ' transpose your matrix.

Now when you use the following:

```
for k=1:10
d=k*3;
disp(d)
end
```

You claim you are seeing a column. What looks like a column on your display is actually a series of scalars. Here you declare a for loop, at each iteration k is a scalar (no longer a row or a column). Then d is a scalar too and you display it on screen. You do not have a column but a scalar at each iteration.

Finally

```
 k=1:10;
 if k==5
 d=7
 else
 d=k*3
```

This time k is a row, but your if statement compares a row to a scalar. It's not surpring it does not behave as you expected.